# why is java math.round always rounding down?

Tags: java, math, rounding

I have a number of fields which take inputs, a process which happens and then fields that show the output. My issue is that for some reason math.round seems to be always rounding down instead of to the nearest integer.

Here is an example

```
private void method(){
    int X= Integer.parseInt(XjTF.getText());
    int Y= Integer.parseInt(YjTF.getText());

    float Z =(X+Y)/6;

    int output  =  Math.round(Z);

    OutputjTF.setText(Integer.toString(output)+" =answer rounded to closest integer");
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `X` and `Y` variables are `int`, so Java performs integer division, here when dividing by 6.  That is what is dropping the decimal points.  *Then* it's converted to a `float` before being assigned to `Z`.  By the time it gets to `Math.round`, the decimal points are already gone.

Try casting `X` to `float` to force floating point division:

```
float Z =((float) X + Y)/6;
```

That will retain the decimal information that `Math.round` will use to properly round its input.

An alternative is to specify a `float` literal for `6`, which will force the sum of `X` and `Y` to be cast to `float` before the division:

```
float Z = (X + Y)/6.0f;
```

It can't just be `6.0`, because that's a `double` literal, and the Java compiler will complain about "possible loss of precision" when attempting to assign a `double` to a `float`.

Here's the relevant quote from the [JLS, Section 15.17.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2):

> Integer division rounds toward 0. That is, the quotient produced for
>   operands n and d that are integers after binary numeric promotion
>   (§5.6.2) is an integer value q whose magnitude is as large as possible
>   while satisfying |d · q| ≤ |n|.